# rounding decimal numbers of results in jquery

Tags: jquery, rounding

I've got this code -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function(){
$("#result").submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var ele = $("#element").val(),
    target = $("#target").val(),
    context = $("#context").val(),
    border = $("#border").val(),
    margin = $("#margin").val(),
    padding = $("#padding").val();

console.log(ele, target, context, border, margin, padding);

var DoubleMargin = parseInt(margin, 10) * 2;
var DoublePadding = parseInt(padding, 10) * 2;
var DoubleBorder = parseInt(border, 10) * 2;


var ActualTarget = parseInt(target, 10) - parseInt(DoubleBorder, 10) - parseInt(DoubleMargin, 10) - parseInt(DoublePadding, 10) * 1;
var result3 = parseInt(target, 10) - parseInt(DoubleMargin, 10) * 1;
var MarginResult = parseInt(margin, 10) / parseInt(target, 10) * 100;
var PaddingResult = parseInt(padding, 10) / parseInt(target, 10) * 100;
var OriginalResult = parseInt(ActualTarget, 10) / parseInt(context, 10) * 100;
var BorderResult = parseInt(target, 10) - parseInt(border, 10) * 1;

//$(".result").append(ele + " " + result + "%");
$("<p></p>", {
    html: ele + " {<br><span>width: " + OriginalResult + "%;" + " /* " + ActualTarget + " (originally " + target + ") / " + context + " */ " + "<br>border: " + border + "px; " + "<br>margin: " + MarginResult + "%; " + "<br>padding: " + PaddingResult+ "%;" + "<br> </span>}"
}).hide().appendTo("#code-results").fadeIn();
   });

}); 

});
```

and I want the results to round the decimal point to just 5 places. I think I should be using

```
var num.toFixed(5)
```

but I can't get it to work

any ideas?

edit: thanks for comments - basically the results for OriginalResult, MarginResult and Padding Result could have a result of  1.0204081632653061%; which I want to only have the first 5/6 fractional points so it's 1.020408% for example. Is there a 'catch all' than can be applied?

I've put it up on jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sturobson/xTEKm/37/ :)

Comment: Are you sure the number is a number, and not a string at the point you're calling `toFixed()`? And where's `num` being defined?

Comment: I've no idea :S basically the percentage results I get from this could be 1.0204081632653061% for example and I need the fractional point to go 5/6 places like 1.020408%. But hoping for a catch all for the maths that's in place. :)

Comment: You show all this code, yet you don't show `num.toFixed(5)` anywhere, nor is it obvious to us where you're trying to use it.  How are we supposed to read your mind where you're trying to use this?  Some clarity please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we don't know where you're trying to use `toFixed()`, here's one example of how you could use it in your code:

```
var OriginalResult = ((parseInt(ActualTarget, 10) / parseInt(context, 10)) * 100).toFixed(5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that `num` is a percentage, and could be, as described in the comments: `1.0204081632653061%` it's being returned as a string. Therefore you need to call `parseFloat()`, in order to retrieve the floating-point number, before you call `toFixed()`:

```
var num = '1.0204081632653061%';
var numTruncated = parseFloat(num).toFixed(5);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eW2uw/);

References:

- [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).
- [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

Comment: where would I put this in my code? I've just cut and pasted it in and  although the jquery works it doesn't apply this code you've provided :S thanks :))

Comment: All you have to do is use the second line (the first line is just to give something to work with, based on your comment). I have no idea where to put it because I can't see where you used the code originally that you said didn't work. But, basically, use it there. You don't have to `alert()` it, just use it in whatever way you were going to use your original `num` variable.

Comment: Great...but what do you want as a percentage?

Comment: oh sorry, the current ones that are percentages that need to only have 5 decimal points are PaddingResult, MarginResult and OriginalResult :)

Comment: Try this [updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xTEKm/38/). I've only logged to console so you can see where the values are coming from.